# Accessing Android iptables through Device Administrator Rights not via rooting

Tags: android, iptables, root-access

I want to write an app that manages the Android iptables (something like DroidWall) without rooting the device. What kind of "device administrator rights" I have to give to my app in this case?

As an example, the following resource file gives my app the right for deleting, modifying or reading anything in the root directory except system:

```
<device-admin xmlns:android="http: //schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-policies>
    <wipe-data />
  </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

What kind of resource file I have to write in order to give my application the rights to alter the Android iptables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What kind of "device administrator rights" I have to give to my app in this case?

There is no such right in the device administration system.

> the following resource file gives my app the right for deleting, modifying or reading anything in the root directory except system

Not according to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminInfo.html#USES_POLICY_WIPE_DATA). It simply allows you to call `wipeData()` on a `DevicePolicyManager` instance. If you have evidence that the documentation is incorrect in this area, I'd love to see a link to that evidence.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So there is no way to alter the iptable without rooting the device?

Comment: @Mustafa: Yes, or building your own custom ROM.

Comment: Thanks for your comment